# mysql 5.6 no se desisntala

Tags: mysql

hola sucede que desinstale mysql 5.6 borre las carpetas que quedan en program file, ProgramData, Users\Use\AppData\Roaming\MySql pero siempre me aparece instalado como puedo borrarlo definitivamente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Saludos lo que debes hacer es previamente parar los servicios de Mysql mediante la terminal de windows y ejecuntadola esta como administrador:

```
Net stop MySQL
Sc delete MySQL
```

una vez detenidos los servicios vamos al panel de control y desinstalamos la version correspondiente.

Ahora nos resta eliminar las respectivas carpetas:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL
C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL
C:\ProgramData\MySQL
```

y si existe tambie borrala:

```
C:\Users\[Usuario]\AppData\Roaming\MySQL
```

con esto solo reinicia el PC y lsto..!!

Comment: he seguido todos esos pasos anteriormente y mysql 5.6 sigue apareciendo como instalado y cuando instalo mysql 8 workbench sigue reconociendo a mysql 5.6

Comment: @WendyAscencio que windows posees ?

Comment: windows 8.1 pro

Comment: @WendyAscencio dentro del listado de los programas a Desinstalar se encuentra "MySQL Installer"  si es asi debes comenzar primero con desinstalar este, luego  MySQL Server

Comment: ya lo había desinstalado antes de mysql server y hago todos los pasos anteriores y siempre aparece en la lista de programas instalados